# How to use python to determine the date according to week numbers?

Tags: python, date

I am at school and we use a horrible school timetable (SWSCUST). There is no ical export so I am trying to use some codes I found only to make it work with my own school timetable.

I tried to get the code that I found (thanks to https://github.com/xcellerator/swscust2ics) to adapt it with my own school timetable. I successfully changed to code to have it scraping my own school timetable (which is dutch) but what I am missing is dates in my school timetable. What I do have is the week number + the day (monday, tuesday etc) So I wanted to parse the week numbers and have python fill in the blanks.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from ics import Calendar, Event
from pathlib import Path
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
import sys
import arrow
import time

(...)

# Open the HTML file as a string
def importCalendarHTML(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
    return data

# Add a new event to the TimeTable
def AddTimeTableEvent(tt, day, start, end, desc, type, room, staff, dates):
    tt.append(TimeTableEntry(day, start, end, desc, type, room, staff, dates))

# Split the raw HTML into tables via each day
def ParseDays():
    raw_html = importCalendarHTML(sys.argv[1])
    Days = []
    for i in ["maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag", "vrijdag"]:
        try:
            Days.append(pd.read_html(raw_html, header=0, match=i))
        except:
            continue
    #print(pd.read_html(raw_html, header=0, match=i))
    #print(Days)
    return Days

def WeekDays(day):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    start = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
    end = start + timedelta(days=day)
    return end

# Pull out each entry from a table to and compile an entry
def BuildTimeTable(Days):
    TimeTable = []
    for i in range(len(Days)):
        for j in range(len(Days[i])):
            for k in range(len(Days[i][j])):
                day = Days[i][j].get("Dag")[k]
                start = Days[i][j].get("Begintijd")[k]
                end = Days[i][j].get("Eindtijd")[k]
                desc = Days[i][j].get("Opmerking")[k]
                type = Days[i][j].get("Activiteit")[k]
                room = Days[i][j].get("Locatie")[k]
                staff = Days[i][j].get("Docent")[k]
                dates = Days[i][j].get("Weken")[k]
                dates = dates.split(";")
                print(dates)
                #dag = Days[i][j].WeekDays(day)[k]
                AddTimeTableEvent(TimeTable, day, start, end, desc, type, room, staff, dates)
    return TimeTable

(...)
```

As you can see the ideal situation will be a new def that receives the week number and then comes up with the dates that correspond to that day. I tried something like this:

```py
def WeekDays(day):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    start = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
    end = start + timedelta(days=day)
    return end
```

(monday, tuesday etc). My python knowledge is still basic and that is why I need to have your help :)
The school timetable is:

```html
<p><span >21</span></p>
<table  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2%' border='1'>
<col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  />
<tr >
<td>Weken</td>
<td>Dag</td>
<td>Begintijd</td>
<td>Eindtijd</td>
<td>Activiteit</td>
<td>Klas</td>
<td>Docent </td>
<td>Locatie</td>
<td>Externe Locatie</td>
<td>Opmerking</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>dinsdag</td>
<td>9:00</td>
<td>10:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>dinsdag</td>
<td>10:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>dinsdag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>woensdag</td>
<td>8:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>woensdag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>donderdag</td>
<td>8:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>donderdag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><span >22</span></p>
<table  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2%' border='1'>
<col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  /><col  />
<tr >
<td>Weken</td>
<td>Dag</td>
<td>Begintijd</td>
<td>Eindtijd</td>
<td>Activiteit</td>
<td>Klas</td>
<td>Docent </td>
<td>Locatie</td>
<td>Externe Locatie</td>
<td>Opmerking</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>maandag</td>
<td>8:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>maandag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>dinsdag</td>
<td>8:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>dinsdag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>woensdag</td>
<td>8:00</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>woensdag</td>
<td>13:00</td>
<td>17:00</td>
<td>**Description</td>
<td>**CLASS</td>
<td>**Teacher name</td>
<td>**ROOM</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**Description</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Regarding your deleted question: Your HTML data contains multiple `table` tags so reading it with `pandas.read_html` will result in multiple nested dataframes. You can then append the nested dataframes into another dataframe:
`calendar_html = pd.read_html(html_table, header=0) # read the tables into nested dataframes` | 
`mycaldf = pd.DataFrame() # initialize your target dataframe` | 
`for i in range(len(calendar_html)):` | 
`----mycaldf = mycaldf.append(pd.read_html(html_table, header=0)[i]) # append each nested dataframe to your target dataframe` | 
`mycaldf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datetime` library allows you to [create a date using a year, week number, and day of the week name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
import datetime

year = "2019"
dates = "27"
day = "dinsdag"
year_week_day = f"{year}/{dates}/{day}"
result_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(year_week_day, "%Y/%W/%A")
```

Comment: It looks like the OP has a fully spelled out day name... if their locale is set correctly, then something like (assuming the year 2019): `datetime.strptime('Tuesday/21/2019', '%A/%W/%Y')` will give you `datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 28, 0, 0)`... but since `%A` uses the locales settings, then the string of `dinsdag/21/2019` should come up the same. That should enable exact dates and not just the start of the week.

Comment: @TomNash Thanks for the code! Why is there an F in the year_week_day? It also looks like something is wrong:

```python
year_week_day = f"{year}/{dates}/{day}"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    year_week_day = f"{year}/{dates}/{day}"
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```
When I remove the f it works but then I get:
```python
ValueError: time data '{year}/{dates}/{day}' does not match format '%Y/%W/%A'
```
I am using python 2.7

Comment: It's called an `f-string` and it's a function of Python3. You won't be able to use it in Python2.7. Just concatenate the strings then with `year + "/" + dates + "/" + day`

Comment: all is good! But found another error with panda looping too much :( will create a new question